# How can I delete an ethernet interface from a firewall using PAN's Python bindings?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how to read the following documentation:

https://pandevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html

This is something I need to learn how to do, but I'm having difficulty doing simple tasks.. Some I can get to work correctly, some I just can't see how to get working.

For example. If I were to add an interface and IP address:

```
from panos import device, firewall, network

fw_ip = "1.2.3.4"
api_username = "admin"
api_password = "pass123!"

#connect to firewall
fw = firewall.Firewall(fw_ip, api_username=api_username, api_password=api_password)

#create interface
interface = network.EthernetInterface(name="ethernet1/5", mode="layer3", ip="192.168.0.1/24")
fw.add(interface)
interface.create()
```

That is straight forward. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to replace/remove/delete/change any elements in an interface. I KNOW this is a matter of me not understanding the documentation. Here's my attempt thus far:

```
interface = network.EthernetInterface(name='ethernet1/5')
fw.delete(interface)
interface.create()
```

but I get the following error:

> TypeError: delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The other methods the documentation point out are remove() and delete() but neither work.

I have a feeling this will be an easy one for someone who reads these often.

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to focus your question title on the technical problem itself enough that someone else who needs to extract _the same information_ from the docs can find this question and learn from its answers. The next person to have a problem understanding PAN's documentation probably won't have _the same_ problem understanding PAN's documentation, so it's important for a title to be specific.

Comment: that said... looking at https://pan-os-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/panos/firewall.html#Firewall.delete, indeed, `fw.delete` takes no arguments other than `self`; so it deletes _the Firewall configuration itself_, it doesn't delete something _from_ that configuration.

Comment: ...I've gone ahead with editing the title to be more narrowly focused on the specific technical problem.

Comment: I appreciate that. This is a two part problem, the technical part and the knowledge part. I should be able to read these documents and determine the technical requirements. I need more practice and I'm hoping that some light shed on this particular issue will help.